# asana-api-php Fatal error: Class 'Error' not found

Tags: php, asana-api

When attempting to use the Asana API PHP library from here https://github.com/Asana/php-asana I get the following error:

Fatal error: Class 'Error' not found in \src\Asana\Dispatcher\OAuthDispatcher.php on line 49

I realise the error is because the authorization is not working - but how can I fix it to actually throw an exception?

Answer (score 0):

you need to figure out if the class Error is exists and in a loader path.

but for now you can wrap problematic code to try.... catch

```
try{
 line 49 code here
}catch(Exception $e){}
```